# How to enable cors on jboss eap 7.3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, cors

I know, this question has been asked a lot,

I have a simple war file of spring boot rest project.

using global cors I am successfully able to resolve cors on tomcat, but same code and config fails on jbos.

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000").allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
```

But even with this config jboss gives cors error.

**So do we need to additionally update jboss configuration to enable cors ?**

[image]

[image]

Adding xml config from here.

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-to-configure-cors-on-wildfly

So after I added filter mentioned in above link, now my request are giving 404 error.

My updated **standalone.xml** file updated code snippet

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="http://localhost:9000"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="*"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="1"/>
        </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Undertow, that's the 'best' way as it would also add those headers on regular resources.
See http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-to-configure-cors-on-wildfly

Comment: After adding the filter, its giving 404 error. PS I am using jboss 7.3

Comment: Could you share your configuration ?

Comment: yes sure, sharing the standalone.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Actually problem is **not related to CORS error as browser shows in the network tab. It is misleading**.

To start of I tested the api from postman and when deployed on jboss and it was giving **404 error**. And this was the main problem.

Then I searched and found **how to deploy spring boot war on jboss** and found the missing links.

**Update-1. Spring boot main class**.

Instead of just adding global cors config, have to extend springbootservletinitializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CorsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CorsApplication.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CorsApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000").allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Update-2** Have to add **javax.servlet-api** dependency in pom. And exclude the **embedded tomcat** from spring-boot-starter-web.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>CORS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>CORS</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    </build>
</project>
```

So after these 2 changes deployment on jboss was successfull. And their is no need to change anything in standalone.xml file.